# Requesting Next.js web service through public http route returns 404 error on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: node.js, deployment, routes, next.js, digital-ocean

### Problem

I am setting up an App Platform on Digital Ocean using a *Strapi web service component* as CMS and a *Next.js web service component* as Front-End. Strapi is accessible on the route `/api` and Next.js on `/sporus`. According to the runtime logs building and deployment are both successful and no errors are shown. When I try to access my Next.js web service through the route`/sporus` I am met with a 404 screen. Strapi on `/api` is working including the admin panels and requests.

### Goal

Next.js Webservice is accessible through the `/sporus` route and does not return a 404.

### What I've tried

- Set `npm run start` to `next start -H 0.0.0.0 -p ${PORT:-8080}` according to two guides by Digital Ocean [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-to-app-platform) [video](https://youtu.be/1ldjq5M7cbw?t=363).
- Added `basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH` to next.config.js according to the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath)
- Checked if Next.js was served on the standard domain provided on creation of the App Platform instead of custom domain.

### Files

#### next.config.js

```js
const domains = (process.env.APP_URL) ? [process.env.APP_URL] : ['localhost'];

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    domains: domains,
  },
  basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH,
}
```

#### env variables

App wide:

```yaml
- key: STRAPI_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: ${APP_URL}/api
- key: NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: ${APP_URL}/api
- key: DATABASE_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: ${db.DATABASE_URL}
- key: APP_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: ${APP_URL}
```

Next specific:

```yaml
key: NEXT_URL
    scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
    value: ${APP_URL}/sporus
  - key: BASE_PATH
    scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
    value: /sporus
```

### N.B.

I have very little experience with D.G. App Platform & Next.js or deploying node.js servers in general. Most of my projects I run locally so I apologise if this question isn't very descriptive. All additional debugging steps or general tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is quite easy. It is a 'double route' issue. Digital Oceans app platform routes to the next.js webservice but next.js doesn't see this request. Next.js will add the `baseUrl` on top of the route. My webservice was available on `/sporus/sporus` instead of just `/sporus`.

By setting `baseUrl` back to it's default the issue has been resolved.